# How to read all sent items from hotmail by javax.mail?

Tags: java, email, smtp, pop3, hotmail

I find lot of example for read Inbox by pop3.live.com port 995 ...

I find lot of example for sent a message by "mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com" port 587 ...

But I looking for how to read all sent items? I need use smtp or pop?

Comment: Neither POP nor SMTP store outgoing messages. IMAP might be the protocol you're looking for.

Comment: I do not find IMAP example